Python - trying to split int from a string
I'm doing challenges from codewars and am in the middle of an attempt to solve one.
I have questions regarding one of my steps to solve that challenge.
I want to turn a string into a list, where each element of the list are the parts of the string separated by coma.
Here is my attempt:
strg = "01|15|59, 1|47|6, 01|17|20, 1|32|34, 2|3|17"

def stat(strg):
    strg = [x.split() for x in strg.split(',')]

I was expecting
strg[0] = 01|15|59

but I'm getting
strg[0] = 0

and I don't understand why, since I asked to split by ",".
Additional question:
While thinking I got confused... According to the context above, can someone also explain me the difference between:
strg[0]
stat(strg[0])
stat[0]

I printed the different results to see, but since I'm creating a function, I would be tempted to use stat(strg[0]) or stat[0] instead of strg[0] to check the first value of the list?

You have strg outside the stat function, and also inside it. Which one are you testing?

I assumed it would be the same, as I'm declaring the variable before the function, then using it inside that function? strg is not being "updated" after going in the function? (new to python also)

stat(strg) should return strg so that you can do strg_parts = stat(strg)

You can just use strg= strg.split(', ') (note the space after the comma). You're splitting it twice. You're also not modifying the original string because your function isn't returning anything

You're not using your stat fonction. You should moreover return instead of modify the local variable directly.
The split function split a string into a list where each word is a list item so the result is already a list.
strg = "01|15|59, 1|47|6, 01|17|20, 1|32|34, 2|3|17"

def stat(strg):
    return strg.split(',')

The result of the stat function is
>>> stat(strg) 
['01|15|59', ' 1|47|6', ' 01|17|20', ' 1|32|34', ' 2|3|17']

You can pick up the first item of the list:
>>> stat(strg)[0]
'01|15|59'

To answer your additional questions,

strg is a string object so it works as a list of characters, if you type strg[0] you will get the first element of the str
>>> strg[0]
'0'


Your stat function split the argument by ", " but strg[0] does not contain ", " so the stat function returns a list with just the argument
>>> stat(strg[0])
['0']
>>> stat(strg[0])[0]
'0'


Finally, the stat function has to be applied to something. You want here to get the first element of a function object which is not possible.
>>> stat
<function stat at 0x00000264A22BB920>
>>> stat[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable



regards,

In essence, your main question is that I think you are expecting the function to change the immutable string strg. But that is not how Python works.
strg inside the function is a completely different object from the one outside the function. When you change strg inside the function, and then the function exits, that strg may as well never have existed.
You probably want to return from the function.
def stat(strg):
    return [x.split() for x in strg.split(',')]


>>> stat(strg)[0]
['01|15|59']

The main takeaway here is naming and binding, often referred to as scope.

I'm going to rename some variables for you because I think your variable names and the scope they exist in are tripping you up.
original_strg = "01|15|59, 1|47|6, 01|17|20, 1|32|34, 2|3|17"

def stat(temp_strg):
    return temp_strg.split(', ') # added a space after the comma

new_strg = stat(original_strg)
print(new_strg)


With what you had here's what went wrong:
strg = "01|15|59, 1|47|6, 01|17|20, 1|32|34, 2|3|17"

def stat(strg): # this function doesn't return anything
    strg = [x.split() for x in strg.split(',')]
    # this will end up being strg = [['01|15|59'], ['1|47|6'], ['01|17|20'], ['1|32|34'], ['2|3|17']]

stat(strg) # this is only modifying strg within the stat function NOT the original

print(strg) # so this is printing the original

print(strg[0]) # this is just getting the first character of this original

print(stat(strg[0])) # this will end up being [['0']] because you're only giving it the first character of strg

print(stat[0]) # this isn't valid unless you did stat(strg)[0]

